# PRISMA ORM : Using existing DB and adding new models

Tags: node.js, express, prisma

I'm utilizing an already-existing database for my project. I can already use the data in these database's tables because I grabbed the data using "npx prisma db pull" for my project.

The issue is that each time I build a new model for this database, it always complains of database drift and won't let me proceed with my migration unless all the data has been wiped.

"Drift detected: Your database schema is not in sync with your migration history."
"√ We need to reset the MySQL database "pis_system" at localhost"
Do you want to continue? All data will be lost.

i just want to add newer models while the existing data retains

i've tried resetting the db and always importing the data after creating new models. it's tiring